# Name a CSV based on a cell

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I use R and am using the following code to combine multiple csv files

```
> setwd("c:/r data/NASCAR/DK/S1") filenames <- list.files("c:/r
> data/NASCAR/DK/S1") TEMP_files_appended <-
> do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))
> 
> setwd("C:/Users/Adam/Documents/NFL 2017/NASCAR/WINSTON/DK/CSV")
> write.csv(TEMP_files_appended, file ="Daytona2018.csv")`enter code here`
```

My question is how can I instead of having to change the name of the combined file manually every time this one is Daytona2018.csv  i could reference a cell in one of the csv files for example a file named AVG.CSV Cell A1 has text "Daytona_FEB_18_2018"make that the name of the combined files?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: `my_name = AVG.CSV[1, 1];` then `write.csv(TEMP_files_appended, file = paste0(my_name, ".csv"))`.

Comment: Thank you much for leading me in the right direction.  Gonna save me a  lot of time.   Thanks again!!